# use redirect path for signup but it not working. its redirect the home page and show a warning?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

see the code i navigate the path but not working its working for signup but its navigate the '/' router not navigate the pathname .

````
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useToken from "../../../hooks/useToken";

const [createUserWithEmailAndPassword, user, loading, error1] =
    useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, { sendEmailVerification: true });
  let errorElement;
  const [token] = useToken(user);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/";
  if (token) {
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
  }```

Warning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`Signup`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Signup`, follow the stack trace as described in.(react_devtools_backend.js:3973 )
show the warning for the navigation but i navigate the selected path not the home or '/'
````

Answer (score 0):

The navigation action should be triggered from a `useEffect` hook as an ***intentional*** side-effect instead of in the component body as an unintentional effect.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (token) {
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
  }
}, [navigate, token, from]);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @DrewReese but its not working for the **pathname**. it's not show the **warning** but again go to the **'/' path**.but i wants to go to the**location pathname**.

Comment: What is `location.pathname` in your code example? It doesn't appear to be something it is referencing. Are you referring to the `from` value that was passed in route state? Can you share a more complete code example for where & how that is set and the component that is using the code above?

Comment: this is my RequarAuth.js code `if (!user) {
    return (
      <Navigate to="/signin" state={{ from: location }} replace></Navigate> || 
        <Navigate to="/signup" state={{ from: location }} replace></Navigate>
      
    );
  }` navigate this path . but **signin** get the path **signout** not get the path . but i wants to use path in **signin** and **signup** both .

Comment: @HumairaMitul I see. It looks like in that code `user` value is truthy and causes the second `Navigate` component to be rendered with redirect to `"/signup"` path. In either case though the current location appears to be passed to the target component. I can't tell much more what is going on unless you share a more complete and comprehensive code example. A [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be useful in helping to debug.